# Select and sum unique row where all records with similar row meet condition

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table like this

```
id        hash    count    points
1         accd      1        2
2         ebcd      0        1
3         bace      1        4
4         bace      0        2
5         bace      0        3
6         accd      1        2
```

but want to generate another table where the hash can appear only once and at the same time, summing the value of points if count is 0 or 1. 
Here is the condition i want forced on the table: If there are more than one similar hash having count as either 1 or 0, the row with the count as 0 should be picked in preference to the row with count 1 and the value of points for the rows with count 0 summed (if they are more than one).
The result of the table i want generated is shown below.

```
id        hash    count    points
1         accd      1        4
2         ebcd      0        1
3         bace      0        5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  One method is:

```
select min(id) as id, hash, count,
       (case when min(count) = 0
             then sum(case when count = 0 then points end)
             else sum(points)
        end) as points
from t
group by hash, count;
```

Another method is to put the logic in the `where` clause:

```
select min(id) as id, hash, count, sum(points)
from t
where t.count = 0 or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.hash = t.hash and t2.count = 0
                 )
group by hash, count;
```

Comment: Which of the two has the least overhead cost?

Comment: Gordon Linoff what is the t2 on the second method? I understand t is the table name.

Comment: @uwem . . . It is a table alias.  As for which has better performance, that depends on the data.  On small data, it won't make a difference, on larger data, you can test to see which is better.